# Tomcat and NodeJS (different IPs) using same SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, tomcat7

My web application uses Tomcat7 for hosting web pages and NodeJS for WebRTC. Each of them has a different IP. We've already set up the ssl certificate of Tomcat. My question is can I use the signed certificate of Tomcat in the NodeJS server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use the installed certificate on your tomcat and NodeJS server.

But, you need to be clear with your common name as there are many different types of certificate available like wildcard ssl, which supports all the sub-domains for a single domain name, multi-domain certificate, which support multiple domain names on a single certificate.

Certificate feasibility depends on your types of certificate, which you can export from apache keystore and import on NodeJS server.

http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html - The following articles will help you for the installation of export certificate from apache to NodeJS server.